# Can't forward remote port to local

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

```
ssh -vvv -R ZZZ.ZZZ.ZZZ.ZZ:1000:localhost:80 root@ZZZ.ZZZ.ZZZ.ZZ -N
```

I can't bind to primary ZZZ.ZZZ.ZZZ.ZZ ip address:

```
debug1: remote forward failure for: listen ZZZ.ZZZ.ZZZ.ZZ:1000, connect localhost:80
Warning: remote port forwarding failed for listen port 1000
debug1: All remote forwarding requests processed
```

but for 127.0.0.1 and remote LAN address it works properly.
Can u explain the issue?
Thank u.

```
# /etc/ssh/sshd_config
GatewayPorts clientspecified
```

Comment: Does it work with ports bigger than 1024?

Comment: @Jakuje no, I have tried any ports, no changes.

Comment: What OpenSSH version?

Comment: @Jakuje OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016

Comment: Does it work with different user?

Comment: @Jakuje No, I've tested on another user.